# Hammerhead Corvette survival

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

Did the Hammerhead Corvette that caused the star destroyer collision survive the battle of Scarif?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### She's dead, Jim

This isn't explicitly confirmed in either the film or the novelization, but...yeah; no.

- In the film, the last we see of the ship it's taking a nosedive towards Scarif:

  [image]

  [image]
- In the novel, the last we hear of the ship sees it being [trapped](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/147695/31051) in Scarif's gravitational pull (emphasis mine):

  > The *Lightmaker* [Hammerhead corvette] picked up speed as it approached the fray, pulled by Scarif's gravity as it pushed with its engines toward the disabled Destroyer. The second Star Destroyer seemed to realize what was happening, but much too late; caged by Red and Gold Squadron fighters, it could go nowhere in time to escape its fate.
  >
  > *[...]*
  >
  > The disabled Star Destroyer drifted toward its caged twin. Oquoné's course had been set with precision. As the Alliance starfighters broke away, the two Destroyers collided. Both ships flared with destructive power, and **both tumbled more swiftly as Scarif's gravity gripped them**. Locked together by cataclysmic devastation, their entwined wreckage plummeted toward the inner ring of the orbital gate station.
  >
  > <sup>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story - Official Novelization* Chapter 20</sup>

  Also notable: both ships are described as "wreckage", not a good condition for a ship to be in.
- Also from the novel, the *Lightbringer* was chosen specifically for the job because it had been heavily damaged; what's more, it made the run with a skeleton crew:

  > He had chosen the Hammerhead *Lightmaker* and its captain, Kado Oquoné, to implement his vision. Oquoné's ship had been badly damaged after being flanked by the twin Destroyers, and had since withdrawn from the field of fire to guard the line of retreat. For these reasons it would serve Raddus’s purpose.
  >
  > "Are you prepared, Captain?" He spoke to Oquoné from the bridge of the Profundity, his eyes fixed on his tactical display.
  >
  > "Nonessential personnel have evacuated," Oquoné replied. "It's just me, a skeleton crew, and a handful of droids. Course is locked." His voice did not tremble. Raddus gave him credit for that; when he'd explained his intent, Oquoné had reacted angrily—yet only for an instant. Since that moment, the captain had been nothing but resolved.
  >
  > <sup>*Rogue One: A Star Wars Story - Official Novelization* Chapter 20</sup>

  Nobody really expected this to end well for the *Lightmaker*.
- In [an interview](http://ew.com/movies/2017/01/12/rogue-one-mystery-hammerhead-crew/) with *Entertainment Weekly*, John Knoll (a LucasFilm bigshot and executive producer on *Rogue One*) revealed that the creative team had originally planned to show escape pods making their way from the ship...

  > "There was some talk about, 'Hey, is this a suicide mission? Are all these guys going down with the Star Destroyers?' I started pushing for this idea that maybe in one of the shots we could have all these lifeboats, the escape pods, shoot out of it."
  >
  > *[...]*
  >
  > "The last shot you see of the Star Destroyers crashing down through the gate — it’s a very subtle thing, and it would probably be hard to tell this – but the lifeboats are all gone on the Hammerhead," Knoll tells EW. "It's my story that the Hammerhead crew got into the life boats and made it out."

  ...right onto the surface of Scarif:

  > "Our story was that they made it down to the surface of Scarif, and were standing around the beach going, 'You know what, it isn't so bad here!'" Knoll says.
  >
  > Then, as the Death Star fires up its laser... "'Hey, what's that bright thing on the horizon?'"

In all probability, the *Lightmaker* crashed on Scarif, where its wreckage may or may not have then been obliterated by the Death Star.